# howto rewrite engine rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm trying to understand some rules or rewrite engine but i can't figure how to do it.

i have this link:

```
w**.example.com/index.php?city=new+york
```

and i wish to rewrite to this new:

```
w**.example.com/good-parties-in-new-york
```

the value of city can change to any other city.
but the point here is I only what to rewrite if all the key is:

*index.php?city=*

because the

*index.php?zone=*

is used for other things, etc...
any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused on what exactly you want to achieve. URL rewriting is normally done to make URLs look nicer, not the other way around.

You would typically want to have a nice URL like this (which you'd communicate to your users):

```
w**.example.com/good-parties-in-new-york
```

act as an "alias" for a not-so-nice looking URL like this (= the actual page being served, unbeknownst to the users):

```
w**.example.com/index.php?city=new+york
```

With Rewrite, you can backreference regular expressions. In this case, you could convert parts of the "nice" URL into RegEx's which you would then backreference with variables in the query string of the page working in the background.

E.g.:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^good-parties-in-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)$ index.php?city=$1+$2 [NC,L]
```

The first RegEx (`([a-z]+)`) is referenced as `$1`, the second as `$2` (and so on).

Note that this example will only work for city names consisting of two words, like New York, San Francisco etc. You'll have to figure out of how many words city names can consist of and rewrite your code accordingly. (You might also have to set different flags.)

Plus, you should make sure that your php script checks against existing city names and throws an appropriate error/gives out a warning if users enter fantasy names like good-parties-in-magical-rainbow-city or similar.

If this isn't what you're looking for, maybe you could clarify your question?