# Specific mod rewrite on URL with multiple variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

appreciate help in advance.  I'm using mod rewrite and need help in converting specific PHP URLS into prettier URLs.

Specifically, I want to convert the PHP URL:

www.sample.com/subcategory.php?subcategory=sports-achievement&page=1

to

www.sample.com/sports/sports-achievement.html

for the user.

So to be specific, the rule is:

- a) the first part of the subategory before the dash should be the
  directory (e.g., sports- - into /sports/
- b) the entire subcategory as
  the page string "sports-achievement.html
- c) the PHP pages still needs
  to pass the page strings (as there are multiple pages)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure if you've understood how rewrites work, please check out [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027520/howto-rewrite-engine-rule/18028542#18028542) I wrote to another user first. Once you've read it, my question is: do you need the middle part of your pretty URL (`sports`) for the redirect at all? Or is only the subcategory needed? (What happens if a user surfs to just `www.sample.com/sports`?) Are the names for all other pages the same, i.e. `www.sample.com/x/x-achievement.html` ? Also, where's the page number in the pretty URL?

Comment: Kay - thanks.  I am doing this because I've rewritten a site, and want to match the old URL structure.  There are lots of old inbound links that go directly to pages.  So while I do not "need" sports, that's the exact structure of the old URLs.  If a user goes to "/sports, there is a page their that lists the categories in sports.  (Hierarchy is Category / subcategory / page.)  Now the page number is a good question - thoughts on where to put that?

Comment: Still confused: which is the old URL structure and which is the new one? What are the URLs that users are going to see/be linked to from the page itself in the future?

Comment: Thanks!  User should see: www.sample.com/sports/sports-achievement.html (this is the old URL structure), while the server should see: www.sample.com/subcategory.php?subcategory=sports-achievement&page=1

Comment: Ah. Well, if you don't want to change the URLs that are displayed to the users, you obviously can't work with different page numbers. Meaning you'd always have to load and display all results. If, on the other hand, it'd be ok to change the URLs slightly, you could include them. I'm guessing this comes down to if it's important to keep the URLs for SEO reasons?

Answer (score 0):

To get the the redirect and internal rewrite, you'll have to do something like this.

```
#Redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (GET|POST)\ /subcategory\.php\?subcategory=([^-]+)-([^&]+)(&(.*)|)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^subcategory\.php$ /%2/%2-%3.html?%5 [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)/\1-(.*)\.html$ subcategory.php?subcategory=$1-$2 [QSA,L]
```

There is no real way of hiding the page name. You can use a post-request and hide it in the post-body. My answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859357/2209007) shows how to do it with cookies, but this will most likely confuse search engines, as different pages are somehow available under the same page name.